# ON DELETE CASCADE not being respected

Tags: sqlite

I am using [sqlite-jdbc 3.36.0.3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc) which is a "library for accessing and creating SQLite database files in Java (it includes native libraries)". [SQLite documentation shows](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) that that SQLite does support `ON DELETE CASCADE`. Executing the commands below does not trigger the delete on cascade so therefore "Jon" has been removed, but not "Scruffy" and "Poochy".

Is there a bug with sqlite-jdbc 3.36.0.3? Has anyone else experienced an issue where `ON DELETE CASCADE` is not being respected?

```
CREATE TABLE Person(
    [Id] [INTEGER] PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [Name] [TEXT] NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Pet(
    [Id] [INTEGER] PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [Name] [TEXT] NOT NULL,
    [PersonId] [INTEGER] NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (PersonId)
        REFERENCES Person (Id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO Person(Id, Name)
VALUES (1, "Jon");

INSERT INTO Pet(Id, Name, Person_id)
VALUES (1, "Scruffy", 1), (2, "Poochy", 1);

DELETE FROM Person WHERE Id=1;  -- "Jon" (Person) is removed, but not the pets (Scruffy/Poochy)
```

Comment: The enforcement of foreign keys is off by default (IIRC, for historical compatibility reasons). It can be turned on, however:

https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys

Comment: See also https://sqlite.org/forum/info/659ed3100d70b77e

Comment: Your code runs as expected: https://dbfiddle.uk/YO9nLF4J

Answer (score -1):

`Person` does not reference `Pet` so how should a deleted `Person` know what FK references exist?

Normally you have an FK from the `Person` to the `Pet` that cascades the deletion and the reversed reference, i.e. `1:0-n` -> `1 Person: 0-n Pets`.